Table-valued parameter performing poorly in EF Core vs T-SQL directly
I have a custom table type (object/column names obfuscated)
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[myTable] AS TABLE
(
    my_id    BIGINT, 
    my_name  VARCHAR(100),
    my_value VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

And a procedure that uses it as an input parameter:
CREATE OR ALTER procedure my_merge_sp
    (@downloaded_records [myTable] READONLY,
     @last_updated_on    DATETIME,      
     @last_updated_by    VARCHAR(128))
AS
BEGIN
    -- DO STUFF
END

When using SSMS, I declare a new instance of myTable and insert 200K records into it, and call my stored procedure. It takes 2 seconds.
When using EF Core, I declare a new SqlParameter using a DataTable that matches the shape of the type, and put the same 200K records in it. The command that executes the stored procedure times out (with a command timeout set to 120 seconds).
FWIW, I tested this call with 50 records from EF Core and it took 1 second, and the stored procedure did what it was supposed to, so the EF Core is wired up correctly from that standpoint.
But otherwise, what is the key difference between what EF Core is doing and what is going on in SSMS to account for that massive performance difference? And what tricks can I leverage to bring the EF Core performance to be more on par with SSMS?

Avoid EF Core's LINQ-based abstractions for stored procedures. Use raw SQL for passing the TVP. dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC MyStoredProcedure @MyTable", parameter);

@TharukaDeshan - thx for the suggestion. So in my case, with 200K rows, would I just be creating a massive string with 200k individual inserts? Like a stringbuilder of epic proportions?

Dont think the problem is linq, unless it takes a lot of time to populate the tvp itself. Probably your procedure has some bad query plans cached. Try adding a pk to the tvp perhaps and check the running query and it's queryplan

Among other things SSMS defaults to SET ARITHABORT ON, unlike most other connection methods, so EF probably has a different and unfavorable query plan cached already.

I feel huge difference in your tests. Table populated on the SQL Server side and there is no network between you SP and Table. In case of TVP, you should send megabaytes over network before SP call.

Please show how you create the TVP using EF Core. It's possible there is an implicit conversion going on. Please also show what -- DO STUFF actually is, as well as relevant tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

@siggemannen - wouldn’t the cached query plan affect the SSMS execution and the EF execution be equally affected by it? If I create a TVP with the same data and pass in the same i put params in both cases and alternate back and forth between them, its 2 sec for SSMS, 2+min for EF Core, 2s, 2+min, 2sec, 2+min, etc, etc…

@AlwaysLearning - if EF is caching its own plans, is there a way to get it to stop? And instead, have it emulate what SSMS is doing?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - I, also, was thinking that it could be in the transmission of the data to the SP, rather than the SP execution itself. The interesting thing is that we certainly have other SP’s that return this same amount of data to the middle tier seamlessly. So I’m struggling to see why sending 200k rows of data to an SP would be prohibitively slow when getting 200K back from an SP is nice and snappy… but there must be some difference. Otherwise, I wouldn’t be seeing this behavior. When you say “should send MB over network before SP”, what specifically are you suggesting?

Your issue isn't EF caching its own plans, that's just a side effect of the fact that SSMS and EF often use slightly different settings, so the server caches them separately. It's a red herring trying to get them to cache together: you might just end up with one cached plan which is poor. The real question is why the poor plan is even possible. And that's why I asked you for some actual info: full proc code, tables, indexes, and slow and fast plans. We simply can't answer otherwise.

You misread what I said - EF doesn't cache its own plans. SQL Server creates and caches plans, and the keys to the plan caches are based on the hash of the complete T-SQL statement (including whitespace) and the current @@OPTIONS value. When SSMS has SET ARITHABORT ON and everything else generally has SET ARITHABORT OFF it can cause different plans to be created and they have the potential to perform wildly differently, i.e.: SSMS can appear to be fast and the application slow. You can turn ARITHABORT off as a default in Query Execution Options in SSMS.

Hi all - Thank you for your contributions to this. It definitely steered me in the right direction. I updated the question with my resolution.

TLDR - WITH RECOMPILE fixed the issue. (explanation below)
Based on the comments section, I tried a few things:
One, I actually gutted the stored procedure so that it was doing nothing but a print statement. I wanted to see if the slowness was caused by the size of the table valued input parameter, or if it was the actual contents of the stored procedure. Without the stored procedure doing anything of substance, it returned very quickly. This ruled out the theory that the data going over the wire was to blame.
Next, I realized that in all of my SSMS tests, I had only tested with large datasets. Through EF Core, I had tested with datasets of all sizes, starting with small ones. Based on what a lot of commenters suggested, SSMS and EF Core may cache plans in SQL server separately from one another. Given that SSMS had only been tested with large datasets, it's only cached plan was one optimized for large datasets.
But given that in EF Core, I had first tested with a small dataset, that was what the cached plan was optimized for, and that's why it was so slow with the large dataset. I updated the stored procedure using the WITH RECOMPILE keyword. This didn't add any significant overhead to the execution. But it did make the calls from EF Core snappy, even alternating between small and large datasets.
Thank you to everyone who commented. The sum of all the comments steered me in the right direction.

It sounds like it's a cardinality estimation issue. Try using Trace Flag 2453 see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/using-trace-flag-2453-improve-table-variable-performance/
